# Return typed object property when accessed by key

Tags: typescript

Hard to explain so here is an example:

```
interface O {
  n: number;
  s: string;
}
const f = (key: keyof O, o: O) => o[key];

const value = f('n', { n: 1, s: '' }); // value type is (string | number)
```

In this situation I'd like `value` type to be `number` because the key `n` points to a `number` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using generic syntax for the `f` function. For an anonymous function like you have there you could do:

```
const f = <O, K extends keyof O>(key: K, o: O) => o[key];
```

This allows typescript to infer the `key` parameter to be a specific key of the `O` object, where before it couldn't be narrowed to anything more specific than just `keyof O` (which represents the union of all keys).

Now, your example will give the right type for each key:

```
const value = f('n', { n: 1, s: '' }); // value type is: number
const other = f('s', { n: 1, s: '' }); // other type is: string
```

Comment: great! so this solution does not depend on interface itself, right ?

Comment: Thanks, that works! And `O` does not need to be a generic. You can just do: `f = <K extends keyof O>(key: K, o: O) => o[key]`. But then I don't understand why it works and this doesn't: `f = (key: keyof O, o: O) => o[key]`